# calling variables from a class to a subclass

Tags: java, class, hierarchy

I am trying to set the endpoints of a trapezoid, square, etc. 
For example: `TRX` (top right x) is 2 and `TRY` (top right y) is 2, so the top right point is at `(2,2)`.  I am wondering how to use the variables in the subclass with the given hierarchy:

```
public class Quadrilateral {
    private int TRX, TLX, BRX, BLX;
    private int TRY, TLY, BRY, BLY;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}

class Trapezoid extends Quadrilateral {
}

class Square extends Quadrilateral {
}
```

Comment: Use getters and setters?

Comment: You cannot access a `private` attribute in a subclass.  You'll either need to make it `protected` or add `getXYZ()` methods.  That said, working through a Java tutorial would probably be useful.

Comment: Demo? Just wondering what the syntax would look like

Comment: @chrylis Using setters would be fatal in this example.  In contrary, the attributes should be made `final`.  How else could a `Square` ensure it's class invariants?

Comment: can you say that a little for "dumbed down"? im like 2 weeks into this.

Comment: @user1914650 This is a trivial exercise and sounds very much like homework.  I don't know how to give you a demo without doing your homework.  Maybe work through a tutorial like I've suggested.

Comment: Well of course its Homework. I'm just looking for a start is all.

Comment: like what is a getXYZ()?

Comment: It's a `getter` method for XYZ class variable.

Comment: Try [`Inheritance Tutorial`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). If it's too difficult then start with very basic stuff.

Comment: Also read http://stackoverflow.com/q/215497/2654518